# rails cannot load such file -- mysql2/mysql2 (LoadError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I am newbie to ruby on rails i could not find the solution for this error:

```
rails s
```

---

```
/usr/local/share/gems/gems/mysql2-0.3.13/lib/mysql2.rb:8:in `require': cannot load such file -- mysql2/mysql2 (LoadError)
from /usr/local/share/gems/gems/mysql2-0.3.13/lib/mysql2.rb:8:in `<top (required)>'
from /usr/local/share/gems/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `require'
from /usr/local/share/gems/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `block (2 levels) in require'
from /usr/local/share/gems/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:70:in `each'
from /usr/local/share/gems/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:70:in `block in require'
from /usr/local/share/gems/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:59:in `each'
from /usr/local/share/gems/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:59:in `require'
from /usr/local/share/gems/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler.rb:132:in `require'
from /home/Harish/Documents/simple_cms/config/application.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
from /usr/local/share/gems/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/commands.rb:76:in `require'
from /usr/local/share/gems/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/commands.rb:76:in `block in <top (required)>'
from /usr/local/share/gems/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/commands.rb:73:in `tap'
from /usr/local/share/gems/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/commands.rb:73:in `<top (required)>'
from bin/rails:4:in `require'
from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
```

Comment: This question does not provide anywhere near enough information for us to debug it. Please at least show us your Gemfile.

Comment: I found the question via Google. My solution was `sudo gem install mysql2`.

Answer (score 16):

```
gem uninstall mysql2

gem install mysql2 --platform=ruby
```

delete the mysql2 gem directory in your rails specific bundle directory and copy paste this newly install mysql2 gem

Answer (score 6):

For Rails 3.2.17 and Ruby 1.9.3-p448 and mysql2 0.3.11, running `bundle update mysql2` updated to 0.3.15 and got rid of the error for me.

Comment: Thanks! also if there is error after this command try to remove mysql2 and install again && brew update mysql2. For me this works!

Comment: You mean `brew upgrade mysql2`

Answer (score 1):

Ya, It's happening with new version(0.3.13) of mysql2 gem with rails 4.0.0. Deleting the bundle folder under vendor directory, and rerunning bundle install, update fixed this issue for me

```
cd {Your_RailsApp_Root}/vendor/
rm -rf bundle/
cd {Your_RailsApp_Root}
bundle install
bundle update
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the mysql2 gem installed? Check that your gemfile has `gem "mysql2"` and then run `bundle install` from the root of your rails app. Also, ensure that you mysql downloaded in your development environment.

Comment: yes i have installed the gem mysql and i have it in the gem file also

Answer (score 0):

just downgrade the mysql2 version. In my case, I used '0.2.6' version and it worked for me.

```
  gem 'mysql2', '0.2.6'
```

with ruby version 2.0.0 and gem version 1.8.25

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo installer -pkg /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Packages/macOS_SDK_headers_for_macOS_10.14.pkg -target /
```

from 
`https://gorails.com/setup/osx/10.14-mojave`

Answer (score 0):

I battled this for a day when running into it while trying to run `bundle exec rake db:migrate` after successfully `bundle install`ing my project gems.

For me, `mysql2` was trying to load a configuration file that didn't exist. I had already `brew install`ed mysql on my system, and what mysql2 was looking for existed already in the mysql installation. I ran

```sh
gem install mysql2 -v 0.5.3 -- --with-mysql-config=/usr/local/Cellar/mysql@5.6/5.6.42/bin/mysql_config --with-ldflags=-L/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib --with-cppflags=-I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include
```

to point mysql2 to the correct configuration.

NOTE the version you have of mysql may be different and the version of the gem you want may also be different.
ALSO NOTE: the gem install path **may** be different than your `bundle install` path. You can also the gem to your bundle directory with

```
gem install --install-dir /path/to/bundle/directory
```

OR you can set gem options with your bundle build configuration:

```
bundle config --local build.mysql2 --with-mysql-config="/usr/local/Cellar/mysql@5.6/5.6.42/bin/mysql_config" --with-ldflags=-"L/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib" --with-cppflags=-"I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include"
```

Answer (score 0):

Apple silicon M1:

```
gem install mysql2 -v '0.5' -- --with-opt-dir=$(brew --prefix openssl)
```

Answer (score -1):

It work for me.

- gem uninstall mysql2
- sudo gem install mysql2
- bundle

Comment: I would strongly recommend against using `sudo` to install Gems unless you specifically know that's required for your circumstances. Generally, it isn't required.

Answer (score -7):

this solved my error:

[root@localhost cms]# su Harish

[Harish@localhost cms]$ bundle install

[Harish@localhost cms]$ rails s