# first rails app problems [require libmysqlclient.so.18 LoadError]

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, runtime-error

i have problems running for first time the "rails server".
 take a look..

> alvaro@debian:~/rails/rc/rgcl$ rails server
>   /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/rails/script_rails_loader.rb:11: warning: Insecure world writable dir /home/alvaro/springsource/grails-2.2.4/bin in PATH, mode 040777
>   /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/bundler/runtime.rb:211: warning: Insecure world writable dir /home/alvaro/springsource/grails-2.2.4/bin in PATH, mode 040777
>   /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/mysql2-0.3.17/lib/mysql2.rb:8:in `require': /opt/lampp/lib/libmysqlclient.so.18: symbol SSL_accept, version OPENSSL_1.0.1 not defined in file libssl.so.1.0.0 with link time reference - /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/mysql2-0.3.17/lib/mysql2/mysql2.so (LoadError)
>       from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/mysql2-0.3.17/lib/mysql2.rb:8:in`'
>       from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/bundler/runtime.rb:68:in `require'
>       from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/bundler/runtime.rb:68:in`block (2 levels) in require'
>       from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/bundler/runtime.rb:66:in `each'
>       from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/bundler/runtime.rb:66:in`block in require'
>       from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/bundler/runtime.rb:55:in `each'
>       from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/bundler/runtime.rb:55:in`require'
>       from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/bundler.rb:119:in `require'
>       from /home/alvaro/rails/rc/rgcl/config/application.rb:7:in`'
>       from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/rails/commands.rb:53:in `require'
>       from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/rails/commands.rb:53:in`block in '
>       from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/rails/commands.rb:50:in `tap'
>       from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/rails/commands.rb:50:in`'
>       from script/rails:6:in `require'
>       from script/rails:6:in`'

i don't know why there are the grails directory? and how i can solve the error with the mysql library.?
PD:i need use mysql.

regards

Comment: did you make some research? libmysqlclient installed ?

Comment: Looks like you have a problem with OpenSSL and your mysql gem is expecting a different version.

Comment: the solution was sudo gem install mysql2  here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18158775/rails-cannot-load-such-file-mysql2-mysql2-loaderror